# Fetch with post data to expressjs leads to 404 server not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Having a react frontend with my own expressjs api backend.
Express v. 4.16.0

Using fetch on the react frontend to get data works just fine.

```
 fetch('/desResData')
      .then(res => {....}
```

As soon as I try to post some data with the request I get: "POST http://localhost:3000/desResData 404 (Not Found)"
Code:

```
 fetch('/desResData',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: { product: "test" }, // tried JSON.stringify as well
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
    )
      .then(res => {....}
```

Roughly spoken I can have static communication from front to backend but I cant parametrize my requests.

ExpressJS:

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {

  console.log(req.body) // tried with using req and without using it

  findByProduct("product") // some async db operation // this part is working fine while fetching without any post parameters
    .then(data => {
       res.json()
      })
```

Comment: How  does the express code look like?

Comment: Whats your backend code? Are you using express' `.post(...)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write `router.post` (not `router.get`) to process an HTTP POST request.

Notice the *method* of your fetch is `POST`.  But you wrote `router.get` which handles a request where the *method* is `GET`.

If a POST request comes in for a route that doesn't exist, express will give 404.  This applies even if there is a GET handler for the same route.

(Hint: you can have separate GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. handlers for the same route by using `.get`, `.post`, `.put`, `.delete`, etc.)

Comment: Oh boy thats some pretty basic stuff..... solves the issue, getting some new warnings but at least my message is going through :) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

add this in your server code :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD');
    next();
});
```

inside package.json of your react code :

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:serverport",  <-- server port will be port of your node-express server
```

Comment: The proxy was already set up, adding the header options didnt work for me.